# A drug on the market is not what it seems?

Tags: etymology, idioms, phrase-origin

A “drug on the market” is something in such great supply relative to demand that its price is very low, or it is unsaleable. See for example:

> [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drug+in+the+market)
> *drug on the market*
> A commodity whose supply greatly exceeds the demand for it. For example, Now that asbestos is considered dangerous, asbestos tile is a drug on the market.

A contemporary populist British example may be found in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efrXfJydUMI
The strapline for this video clip is "*NOBODY BUYS IT! Meghan's Merch Is A Drug On The Market As Being Refused By All Distributors:*"

This stands in weird contrast with contemporary reality that drugs (in the literal meaning of the word) may command good prices when “on” (in the sense of being “offered in”) the market. They do not necessarily depress the market.

Ngram shows usage (see below) from the 19th century onwards, reaching a peak in the mid 20th century. Most of this usage from 1900 onwards appears to be medical rather than idiomatic . In contrast, the phrase is used idiomatically in many of the examples pre-1900. Here are two examples:

> [Lectures on the History of Protection in the United States, 1988](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Lectures_on_the_History_of_Protection_in/MyjPAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+drug+on+the+market%22&pg=PA59&printsec=frontcover)
> William Graham Sumner, Page 59
> "In 1868 and 1869, we saw mutton a drug on the market at 8 and 9 cls., when beef was 20. The farmers who had been deluded into relying on tariffs to produce wealth, found that they had to send their sheep to slaughter."

An early example from 1868 is

> [1868](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Reports_from_Her_Majesty_s_Consuls_on_th/P93NAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22drug+on+the+market%22&pg=PA281&printsec=frontcover)
> *Wholesale buyers held back , and what little business offered was done in buckskins and pattern cloths , plain cloths being a drug on the market , and very low prices were tendered for woollen hosiery , the quantity of which was far ...*

In Skeat’s Concise Etymological Dictionary of the English Language we find:

> [Concise Etymological Dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ls_XijT33IUC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=etymology+drogue&source=bl&ots=U84ukzYu9O&sig=ACfU3U1FA8S1nnEXs8pXHb9K7l8Nzv3cjg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3ssaFsIT5AhU8QkEAHVIADLsQ6AF6BAgzEAM#v=onepage&q=etymology%20drogue&f=false)
>
> **Drug.**  (F.)  M.E. *drogge*, *drugge.* — O.F. *drogue*, a drug. Also Ital. and Span. *droga.*  Origin unknown; perhaps Oriental.  Der. *drugg-ist*.

A *drogue* is a device used to slow or stop motion:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drogue)
> *drogue*
>
> 1. any funnel-like device, especially one of canvas, used as a sea anchor
> 2. a small parachute released behind a jet aircraft to reduce its landing speed

Such a drug (drogue) would act on the market so as to slow or stop it.

May we therefore surmise that the origin of the phrase lies not in any use of *drug* in the modern sense, but in the idea of something dragging on and slowing the market, rather in the manner that a ship’s motion is slowed by attaching a drogue?

Addendum: Here is the ngram graph.

[image: a drug on the market]

Comment: It's as likely to come from *drag* as *drogue* IMO.

Comment: The assertion "contemporary reality that drugs command good prices" isn't true, their price varies as any other commodity. Some are expensive (Zolgensma), others are cheap (Ibuprofen).

Comment: @StuartF because the function of a *drogue* is to exert a resistive *drag* on the motion, you may well be correct, but the two are probably inextricable in this usage. Middle French drogue, Dutch droog, German tragen, even Russian droshky (a dragged carriage) all show the same root.

Comment: @WeatherVane point taken in detail,  although a (literal) drug on the market cannot generally be assumed to be something of no value. I have edited to make this clearer.

Comment: You don't appear to be using the modern US meaning of "on the market".

Comment: @HotLicks which meaning do you have in mind?

Comment: @Anton - In the US, "on the market" generally means "for sale", with the implication that the product is readily available, and it can be purchased through "normal" channels.  (Of course, the meaning of "normal channels" may be said with tongue in cheek when talking about illicit drugs and such.)

Comment: I can't find a dictionary that doesn't define "on the market" as "available for sale."  Voting to close.  If you want to make a bald statement like your first sentence, please provide documentation.

Comment: @aparente001 if you read all the question you will find I gave an early example. I have added a contemporary reference at the beginning to help justify my statement.

Comment: @HotLicks correct. However, the idiom has more implications than that. My question now gives you two examples rather than the single early one I hoped would make the matter clear.

Comment: Much better, thanks.  But the various definitions and discussions (from a variety of dictionaries, assembled by the Free Dictionary all on one page) seem to be saying that the expression had nothing to do with the word "drug" in its medicinal sense.  And I haven't seen anything in your post or at your link to suggest that anyone uses that phrase in the current day and age.  It appears to be archaic.

Comment: @aparente001 From your comments I begin to suspect a British/American divide. For an excellent contemporary example that is focused on populist British usage, try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efrXfJydUMI The idiom is well understood in Britain, where it is far from archaic. Regarding "drug", I hope it is clear from my question that I do not associate the word as used in this idiom with its medicinal sense. I argue that it is likely to be associated with "drogue".

Comment: You might be onto something.  I wonder if one can separate out UK-US English with ngram.  By the way, including your ngram results as a graph would further improve your post.

Comment: @aparente001 Answer modified again to take some account of your constructive comments. I think we are reaching the limit of what is acceptable in commentary, especially as the question is so close to closure for "lack of clarity". The core of the question is about drug, drogue and drag, which I felt was put clearly enough to attract interest. However, life is short and there are limits to my persuasive powers.

Comment: Gold star for persistence.  The key to reopening is improving the question and you've already got one reopen vote.  Would you mind putting in the ngram graph you cited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probable and supported origin of *drug* in the idiom 'a drug on the market' (also with 'in') is from French *drogue* meaning 'a worthless object, an unpleasant object'<sup>**1**</sup>, 'trash, rubbish, cheap stuff'<sup>**2**</sup> (and originally 'drug' as well). The related word *drugget* also comes from French *drogue*, where *drugget* originally referred to a coarse cloth of wool, used for clothing but often put on the floor. *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57982#eid6043610)*, too, suggests a connection to the derivative *droguet* drugget *n.* and *drogue* in the sense 'badly dressed' for the etymology of *drug*, of the sense 'a commodity which is no longer in demand'; however, adds that "further etymology uncertain and disputed". Moreover, *OED* adds the below in the etymology of *drug*:

> It is normally assumed that the depreciative uses originated from the perception of medicinal substances as being unpleasant to take. Corominas hypothesizes instead that the sense ‘worthless thing’ may have been original, which seems possible, although the Celtic etymology he suggests on the basis of this has not been widely adopted.

The first usage of *drug* for this sense is from 1622; however, the earliest citation of the phrase 'drug in the market' is from 1804, and the earliest citation of the phrase 'drug on the market' is from 1921, per *OED*.

Here is the citation from 1622, from *OED*:

> Another commoditie Minerall, namely Copperas,..hath beene so ill gouerned by worke-men vnderselling one another,..and is become a meere drug out of request, by the abundance made and indiscreetly vented, bartered or exchanged. 
> <sub>G. de Malynes *Consuetudo* i. xlii. 215</sub>

Here is the citation from 1804, from *OED*:

> It was in vain that I urged the state of the corn trade during former wars, particularly during the American contest, when com was literally a drug in the market. 
> <sub>*Farmer's Mag.* Aug. 341</sub>

*[The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins](https://books.google.es/books?id=S1YkAQAAMAAJ&dq=origin%20idiom%20%22drug%20on%20the%20market%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%20%22drug%20on%20the%20market%22)* (by Robert Hendrickson) mentions the same French *drogue* connection as the most supported theory; and also provides other plausible origins related to tea/spice trading and the word *dreg*:

> **drug on the market**. ­We use this expression for “something not in demand, something unsalable because the market is glutted or the woods are full of them.” But since the phrase’s first appearance in 1661 no one has figured out just what it means. What drug is referred to? Is it possibly items of trade like the tea and spices that were sometimes called drugs in the past, and, if so, when in early times were markets ever glutted with such rare commodities? Or is *drug* here just a pronunciation of *dreg* in certain English dialects? Take your choice, but the theory that apparently has the most supporters claims that the drug here is from the French word *drogue*, meaning “rubbish.” The word *drug* has been used in this sense, as when Robinson Crusoe, discovering coins in a wreck, cried out: “O Drug! what art thou good for?”

<sub>Note: The figurative sense of *dreg* (used mostly in plural as *dregs*) is "The most worthless part or parts; the base or useless residue; the refuse or offscourings." per *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57649?rskey=K1MwVF&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)*.</sub>

### Of trading 'drugs'

Another possible and plausible origin is in the context of trading, as mentioned in the above source, where tea and spices -called drugs in the past also- might have flooded the market so that supply exceeded demand. This is also related to the etymology of the original sense of *drug*, where the first element of the Middle Dutch phrase *drōghe vate* ‘barrels of dry goods’ (*drōghe* meaning dry) might have been mistaken for the contents which included dried herbs as medicines. This plausible origin of the original sense of *drug* is mentioned both in *OED* and *[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/drug)*.

Much to my surprise, I've even found a more plausible origin in trading which is also related to the second sense of *drug*, narcotic substance. It is in the context of opium trading between Britain and China in the late Georgian and early Victorian era, where the phrase 'a drug on/in the market' originated in this period. Here is the relevant excerpt from the book *[Pacific Century: The Emergence of Modern Pacific Asia](https://books.google.es/books?id=6INXDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT110&dq=origin%20idiom%20%22drug%20on%20the%20market%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiLvviFk4j5AhWBQcAKHdEhCtk4ChDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=origin%20idiom%20%22drug%20on%20the%20market%22&f=false)* (by Mark Borthwick):

> The commerce in opium received a further stimulus in 1833, when by an act of Parliament the British East India Company lost its government-approved monopoly of British trade at Guangzhou. At last, the powerful textile lobby had succeeded in toppling its rival. The denial of the trade monopoly, which had been a lucrative source of revenue to the company, preceded the body’s dissolution a few years later (1858) by Queen Victoria.
>
> The immediate effect of the deregulation of the British trade was to cause a flood of new merchants to attempt entry into it, resulting in a vast oversupply of goods being brought to Chinese ports. The trade in opium was no exception, and for a time its price plummeted (the phrase “a drug on the market,” meaning an excessive supply of an item amid saturated demand, comes from this period). Many firms went bankrupt or retired from such commerce.

### A connection to 'drag' from the nautical term *drogue*

I've also found a connection to *drag* through the origin of the nautical term *drogue* (a device used to reduce the speed or improve the stability of a boat, similar to a sea anchor); however, it is a conjecture as well. Here is the relevant excerpt from the origin of *drogue* from *[The Language of Sailing](https://books.google.es/books?id=3nh0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT77&dq=%22a%20drug%20on%20the%20market%22%20drag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGutiypon5AhWHLMAKHTRgCj4Q6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22a%20drug%20on%20the%20market%22%20drag&f=false)* (by Richard Mayne):

> Of uncertain origin, but a probable variation of ***drag***, its spelling influenced by the obsolete Scottish and modern French ‘drogue’, drug (itself of obscure origin and first attested *c.* 1377). It would be far-fetched to suggest that a drogue was thought to act as a sedative on the ship: but the expression ‘a drug on the market’ is a further instance of apparent inter-relation among ‘drag’, ‘drogue’ and ‘drug’.
>
> First attested (to denote a device attached to a harpoon line to slow down a whale) in 1725 in *Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society*, XXXII, 263; in its modern boat-slowing sense, in 1875 in Bedford, *Sailor’s Pocket-book* (2nd edition), vi, 220.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57819?redirectedFrom=drogue#eid)* provides a similar etymology of *drogue*, although gives the year 1874 for the first attestation of the word *drogue* as a nautical term from Bedford's *The sailor's pocket book*, 1st edition:

> perhaps originally *drug* , variant of drag *n.*, the form *drogue* arising through assimilation to *drogue* , obsolete and Scots form of drug *n.<sup>1</sup>*

---

<sub>**1** "DROGUE, n. f. au sens de « objet sans valeur, chose de mauvaise qualité », d'où « objet désagréable »." (in the sense of "worthless object, thing of poor quality", hence "unpleasant object".) - https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/drogue</sub>

<sub>**2** "DRUGGET, a coarse woollen cloth. (F.) ‘ And, coarsely clad in Norwich *drugget*, came ;’ Dryden, Mac Flecknoe, 1. 33.—O. F. *droguet*, ‘a kind of stuff that’s half silk, half wooll;’ Cot. Cf. Span. *droguete*, Ital. *droghetta*, a drugget; the latter is given in Meadows, in the Eng.-Ital. section. A dimin., with suffix *-et*, from F. *drogue*, (1) a drug; (2) trash, rubbish, stuff; see Hamilton and Legros, French Dict. See Drug." - *[An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language](https://books.google.es/books?id=jeeGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=french%20drogue%20rubbish&source=bl&ots=rR-2orMTBt&sig=ACfU3U1fWZfaSbj4wwWfaKU7trcApu8YaQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr9rn9wYj5AhXGQ_EDHecoCcoQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=french%20drogue%20rubbish&f=false)* (By Walter W. Skeat)</sub>

Comment: This was one of the most challenging questions I've answered, especially in etymology; and one of the best etymology questions in my opinion, thank you for asking. Apparently, the origin of 'drug' for this sense is still disputed by big names; however I've tried to include further research and analysis on the origin of the idiomatic phrase 'a drug on the market'; which goes deeper in the history of trading. The question deserves recognition.

Comment: drogue is not rubbish. There are two definitions in the TLFi French dictionary: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/drogue The first is about ingredients to make medicines and about drugs like cocaine that are habit forming, basically, while the second from the 19th c. was about **a worthless object** (un objet sans valeur) and some game. So, I don't see rubbish at all.

Comment: @Lambie it is a minor point but Larousse has “ 5. Péjoratif et vieux. Remède fait selon des recettes traditionnelles ; mixture : Confection des drogues et des élixirs”.  “Péjoratif” may well justify (although not mean literally) the notion of rubbish.

Comment: @Anton, péjoratif et vieux does not mean rubbish. The TFLi is more comprehensive than Larousse.

Comment: [An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language](https://books.google.es/books?id=jeeGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=french+drogue+rubbish&source=bl&ots=rR-2orMTBt&sig=ACfU3U1fWZfaSbj4wwWfaKU7trcApu8YaQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr9rn9wYj5AhXGQ_EDHecoCcoQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=french%20drogue%20rubbish&f=false) (By Walter W. Skeat) mentions the meaning 'rubbish' citing another French dictionary: "F. _drogue_, (I) a drug; (2), trash, rubbish, stuff (Hamilton and Legros, French Dict.); i.e. in the latter sense." A worthless object can refer to "rubbish, trash" also.

Comment: My link is a French, authoritative monolingual dictionary showing the meanings in French and eras. Your link is from 1908 and the meanings were supplied by two English speakers.  Those two must have decided to translate un objet sans valeur as rubbish and trash and those are wrong. At least we can locate this now.

Comment: See my link above: II. XIXe siècle. Peut-être issu de drogue I, au sens de « objet sans valeur, chose de mauvaise qualité », d'où « objet désagréable » Maybe from the meaning of drogue `1, a worthless **object**, a poor quality object or **unpleasant object**. Trash, rubbish and stuff is very poor translation. That Hamilton and Legros dictionary is called: The international English and French dictionary and is from 1908 and does not reflect the two meanings, except for the drug, in the TFLi.

Comment: @Lambie I've now added the reference from CNRTL dictionary, thank you for bringing it up. I already know CNRTL and used in my previous answers also; and I've even checked "drogue" there before posting this answer; however I thought it is not a big leap to translate _drogue_ to 'rubbish, trash';  and many credible references mention it. A worthless object and an unpleasant object, as CNRTL puts, strongly refer to 'trash, rubbish' as a more succinct translation. Nevertheless, I've still included CNTRL reference as it is useful.

Comment: I've now added a possible connection to drag from the nautical term _drogue_ as well.

Comment: Thank you for a most carefully researched answer. It complements and modifies massively my own suppositions. You argue convincingly away from the notion of a retarding drag on the activity of the market. ELU at its best.